# bootstrap-modal - How do I stop the background from showing at top when I scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a bunch of long modals that leave no space at the top when they are first rendered. BUT when I scroll up a thin line of background shows at the top. I like this functionality because it indicates that the top of the modal has been reached but my client doesn't and he pays the bills.

You can see this behavior here: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/ by scrolling to the last demo, "Long Modals," launching that demo and attempting to scroll higher than the top (I use a Mac so I drag with two fingers).

HOW DO I STOP THE LITTLE LINE OF BACKGROUND FROM SHOWING?

Comment: What browser & version are you using? Can't reproduce in Chrome 42.0.2311.152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what's setting the gap on top:

```
.modal-overflow.modal.fade.in { top:1% }
```

if you set that to 0 you'll delete the gap